# Is there a way to make a portable iOS backup?

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, backup

I'm travelling and will probably get a new iPad (actually an iPad Pro - woo hoo) while I'm away. Is there a way to backup my current iPad, take the backup with me, and then when I'm near a laptop or family computer restore my current iPad backup to the new iPad?

And for those of you that are going to suggest iCloud backup, my iPad chokes everytime I try to do an iCloud backup and never completes.

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to posit this as an answer.
Though I've never tested it 'in anger' it does work after a migration, so might work on a simple 'file copy'…

Your iTunes 'iDevice' backup is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`
so in theory, carrying that to another Mac ought to allow a restore.

The untested part of my theory is whether or not the iCloud sign-in & encryption factors are also contained within that structure. The sign-in, presumably will just ask you to confirm with your ID & password, then check against Apple's servers, but the encryption [assuming you use it to preserve your passwords etc in the backup] is another factor.

All I could suggest would be to test before it becomes critical - if you have another computer to test with, or even on a new, 'blank' Mac account, before you go away.
If it failed at that point, you'd have your 'real' backup at hand.

As the saying goes, a backup strategy is only as good as your ability to restore it.

Comment: Actually I just found a turnkey solution called iMazing. If this software works (and it has very good reviews) it would be well worth the price. I think it's 34.95. It will let me take my backup with me...the only gotcha might be the iPad itself, which, for whatever reason, is very sluggish. It's a first gen iPad3. 

Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: would be 35 bucks cheaper to test my theory, but I wish you luck - with both backup & travels :)